# CGContextShowTextAtPoint and euro symbol

Tags: ios, encoding, pdf-generation

I am using following to draw text on PDF in iOS:

```
CGContextSelectFont (pdfContext, "Helvetica Bold", 14, kCGEncodingMacRoman);
NSString *str1 = [NSString stringWithString:@"€ 10"];  
CGContextShowTextAtPoint(pdfContext, 25, y-60 , [str1 cStringUsingEncoding:NSMacOSRomanStringEncoding], [str1 length]);
```

The euro sign is displayed as square.

Do you have some suggestions?

ps. i have tries with [str1 UTF8String] too, the same result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most cases it is easier to use NSString Methods `- (CGSize)drawAtPoint:(CGPoint)point withFont:(UIFont *)font` or `- (CGSize)drawInRect:(CGRect)rect withFont:(UIFont *)font` rather than the CoreGraphic equivalents. Apple takes care about thinks like correct transformation, encoding etc. for you.

Comment: if i switch the last line of my posted code with this one: `[str1 drawInRect:CGRectMake(25, y-60, 500, rowHeight) withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14.0]];`  nothing is shown

Comment: did you set a different fill-color before you called drawInRect? If its still the background-color of your context you will see nothing.

Comment: You mean like this: `CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(pdfContext, [UIColor blueColor].CGColor);
  [str1 drawInRect:CGRectMake(25, y-60, 500, rowHeight) withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14.0]];`   In this case i see nothing and i get <Error>: CGContextSetFont: invalid context 0x0

Comment: seems like you have no current context. If you don't create your pdf-context with `UIGraphicsBeginPDFContext...` you have to use `UIGraphicsPushContext(context)` to make your context accessible with `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()` which most UIKit methods depend on.

Comment: I tried this and i can now see the euro sign, but the text is rotated (180 degrees). `UIGraphicsPushContext(pdfContext);
  CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(pdfContext, [UIColor blackColor].CGColor); 
  CGRect rect = CGRectMake(25, y-60, 100, rowHeight);
  UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14.0];
  [str1 drawInRect:rect withFont:font lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap alignment:UITextAlignmentLeft];
  UIGraphicsPopContext();`   How to rotate text 180 degrees

Comment: images and text will be drawn rotated in normal context if you use coreGraphic functions. If you use functions from UIKit apple will do the back-rotation for you. So you should not rotated your context by hand.

Comment: Thanks! What exactly should i use?

Comment: you could flip the context with the following code.`CGContextScaleCTM(c,1,-1);CGContextTranslateCTM(c,0,-contextHight);`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it does anything, but have you tried using `kCGEncodingFontSpecific` for the fourth parameter of your `CGContextSelectFont`? If that doesn't do it, you may have to use [Core Text](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/CoreText_Programming/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005533-CH1-SW1). I've never used Core Text, but it looks like it's text generation is a little more robust than plain ol' Quartz 2D.

To @jonathan-cichon's suggestion, I have also generated PDFs from `UIView`s on which I just put (he proposed NSString's `drawAtPoint`, etc., I actually used plain old `UILabel`s!) and then rendered that to my pdfContext, but that has obvious disadvantages, too. If you're already down the road of PDF context, I'd suggest you pursue Core Text if the kCGEncodingFontSpecific doesn't do it. See this [SO discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505143/how-to-output-a-euro-symbol-in-a-pdf) for other thoughts on the topic.

As a final aside, I found the PDF generation a little limited (but on the other hard, it's amazing that iOS can create PDFs at all). In my case I was frustrated by the lack of font embedding in the PDF, so I ended up creating images of my text rendered by less common fonts (because I was getting the square blocks to which you reference in your problem).

Comment: kCGEncodingFontSpecific didn't help, i tried that before posting

Comment: Then I guess Core Text is the way to go.